# Comparing user input on a form with values on a table MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have made a continuous form which collects data regarding entry into a room. I have included a search box which allows the user to search contacts which have already been entered in a table called "contacts", which then automatically fills certain fields.
What I am trying to accomplish now is to lock certain fields regarding the contact's visit, until certain fields have been filled out. For instance, if a new contact who is not on the table is being entered, I would need the First Name, Last Name, and the company of the user to be entered beforehand (I also have an add contact button which should be clicked after this information is inputted). If this information is not entered, I would require the other fields regarding the visit such as purpose and site of visitation to be locked. This is what I have so far on both the on current and after update events:

```
If IsNull(Me.FirstName) And IsNull(Me.txtLastName) And IsNull(Me.txtCompany) Then
        Me.txtVisitation.Locked = True
        Me.txtDC.Locked = True
        Me.txtPurpose.Locked = True
        Me.Description.Locked = True
    Else
        If IsNull(DLookup("FirstName", "[Merged Table]") = False) Then
            If IsNull(DLookup("txtLastName", "[Merged Table]") = False) Then
                If IsNull(DLookup("txtCompany", "[Merged Table]") = False) Then
                    Me.txtVisitation.Locked = False
                    Me.txtDC.Locked = False
                    Me.txtPurpose.Locked = False
                    Me.Description.Locked = False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Now, this code does run correctly meaning that the fields are locked if these three fields are entered, however for some reason if ONLY the first name is entered (and this first name isn't even on the contacts table) the fields suddenly become unlocked. How can I lock these fields until an actual contact on the contacts table has been inputted?

Comment: You have no filter criteria in any of the DLookup() expressions. Each will simply return value from first record it hits. So of course result is never Null except when table has no records. You name fields with `txt` prefix?

Comment: Also, code is comparing result of DLookup() to Boolean. The `= False` should be outside IsNull() function parentheses.

Comment: Consider using Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly new to access so I never really knew. I will do that :)